# how to track if there is no cell in table view by " if " statement

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

if the table view is empty of cells, like if new user signup to chat app I don't just want the table view to be empty just like that i want to fill it with comment like " go add user or friend " or add button in the middle of the screen leads the users to another view controller to search for friends 
all I want to know where to use " if " statement and how it will be like, then I will do the rest

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchCell
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.user = user
        cell.delegate = self as? SearchTableViewCellDelegate
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Rather than *tracking* the **view** track the **model**. In `viewDidLoad` check `users.isEmpty`. If the result is `true`, show an `UIAlertController` or a popup or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If `users.count` == 0, then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { ... }
```

Will never be called! So maybe in your `viewDidLoad` method you could add a check to see if `users` is not empty. If it is, you could add a subview with the information you want.

Comment: but the table view will show your speech is Theoretical, I want something Practical like real code to understand how its work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom tableview cell with a generic view inside and create two custom views. Depending on what you want you can cast one or another view.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var numberOfCells = 1

        if users.count > 1 {
        numberOfCells = users.count
        }

        return numberOfCells
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if users.count == 0 {
        cell.genericView = CustomView1 as! CustomView1
        //More code if needed
    } else {
        cell.genericView = CustomView2 as! CustomView2
        //More code if needed
    }   

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if users.isEmpty{
   //No cell in table view

    }
   else{
   //Cell in table view

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if users.count  == 0{
        tableView.backgroundView = your custom view whatever you want to show here like : button..
        return 0
    }
    tableView.backgroundView = nil
    return users.count

}
```

You can try this code i hope it'll work as you want...